# How do I give less then equal to on date-time comparison in MySql?

Tags: mysql, datetime

I have to compare date's in mysql, for example:

```
select col1,col2 from table where date <= '2011-12-24' (present date)
```

But this gives an output of all the dates less then '2011-12-24' only.

Comment: What version of mysql are you using ?

Comment: I think a bit more information is needed, could you perhaps provide a simplified table schema, some sample data and the exact sql statements you used to try Aleks G's suggestions? When I tried, all three of them worked.

Answer (score 4):

I suspect your problem is that your `date` column is a timestamp, but you're comparing it to a date.  When this is done, your `2011-12-24` is converted to `2011-12-24 00:00:00.0000` and hence anything that has `2011-12-24` with a reasonable time is after this point.  In your situation, I'd use

```
select col1,col2 from table where my_date < '2011-12-25' (present date + 1 day)
```

or, if you insist on using `<=` then

```
select col1,col2 from table where date(my_date) <= '2011-12-24' (present date)
```

Comment: have tried 2011-12-24 00:00:00 but the result is same as of 2011-12-24

Comment: instead try `<= 2011-12-24 23:59:59`

Comment: the time stamp of data base col are 00:00:00 but i tried using 2011-12-24 23:59:59 even then gives the the same answer as above.. m nt able to get wats going on as mysql supports date comparison

Comment: +1 `my_date < (present date + 1 day)` is the way to go (and it works for either `date`, `timestamp` or `datetime` datatypes).

Comment: or `my_date < (CUR_DATE() + INTERVAL 1 DAY)` in MySQL world.

Answer (score 0):

Well, now try the following.

```
SELECT col1,col2 FROM table 
WHERE date <= STR_TO_DATE('2011-12-24 00:00:00', '%Y-%m-%d %H:%i:%s');
```

This would better help you, if you need the TimeStamp portion in comparision.

`STR_TO_DATE(str,format)` is the inverse of the `DATE_FORMAT()` function.

`STR_TO_DATE()` returns a `DATETIME` value.

The following specifiers may be used in the format string.

The '%' character is required before format specifier characters.

```
Specifier   Description

%a          Abbreviated weekday name (Sun..Sat)
%b          Abbreviated month name (Jan..Dec)
%c          Month, numeric (0..12)
%D          Day of the month with English suffix (0th, 1st, 2nd, 3rd, ?-)
%d          Day of the month, numeric (00..31)
%e          Day of the month, numeric (0..31)
%f          Microseconds (000000..999999)
%H          Hour (00..23)
%h          Hour (01..12)
%I          Hour (01..12)
%i          Minutes, numeric (00..59)
%j          Day of year (001..366)
%k          Hour (0..23)
%l          Hour (1..12)
%M          Month name (January..December)
%m          Month, numeric (00..12)
%p          AM or PM
%r          Time, 12-hour (hh:mm:ss followed by AM or PM)
%S          Seconds (00..59)
%s          Seconds (00..59)
%T          Time, 24-hour (hh:mm:ss)
%U          Week (00..53), where Sunday is the first day of the week
%u          Week (00..53), where Monday is the first day of the week
%V          Week (01..53), where Sunday is the first day of the week; used with %X
%v          Week (01..53), where Monday is the first day of the week; used with %x
%W          Weekday name (Sunday..Saturday)
%w          Day of the week (0=Sunday..6=Saturday)
%X          Year for the week where Sunday is the first day of the week, numeric, four digits; used with %V
%x          Year for the week, where Monday is the first day of the week, numeric, four digits; used with %v
%Y          Year, numeric, four digits
%y          Year, numeric (two digits)
%%          A literal '%' character
%x          x, for any 'x' not listed above
```

Comment: figured it out i jst DATE_FORMAT(date, '%Y%m%d')

Comment: @user1045373:) What do you mean *"figured it out"*? I don't follow what you mean. Do you want me to do so?

Comment: I suggested to use `STR_TO_DATE(str,format)` and not `DATE_FORMAT(date, '%Y%m%d')` as I mentioned that query in my answer and why are you abbreviating *just* to *jst*? English isn't my native language and such expressions may confuse me.

Answer (score 0):

this works... jst need to convert the  column to date format 
  select col1,col2 from table where DATE_FORMAT(date, '%Y%m%d') <= '2011-12-24'